# ggplot Correlational Heatmap With Sums Instead of Correlations

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, geom-tile, ggcorrplot

I have a dataset of legislation that was passed in state houses that is coded into different types of bills. The bills overlap (e.g., a bill could cover topics A and B, or B and C, or just A).

I am trying to create a visualization similar to the correlational heatmap below, but with the total **sums** of values rather than the mere correlations (e.g., there would be 0s, 1s, 2s, 3s, et cetera, for where bills overlap). I think the correlational plot method would look best to capture this information, but I have not seen any that post the sums instead of the correlational values. Does anyone have any ideas about how to approach this issue?
[image]

Thanks as always for the help--I greatly appreciate this community!

Comment: It's not clear what you need here. Can you please share a snippet of your data so we understand what it looks like and also an example of what the rules are for what gets summed and finally how you want to display that in the heatmap?

Comment: @DanAdams sorry for the confusion! I was in the process of getting the data in an anonymized format that I could post here but then Hobo posted the solution. I'll also post a solution in a little bit using some of my example data for anyone else looking for this solution. Appreciate your request for clarity and my apologies for not making it clearer to begin with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question, `geom_tile` should do what you need:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~bill_1, ~bill_2, ~overlap,
      "A",     "A",      10L,
      "A",     "B",       4L,
      "A",     "C",       3L,
      "A",     "D",       2L,
      "A",     "E",       0L,
      "B",     "B",       6L,
      "B",     "C",       5L,
      "B",     "D",       3L,
      "B",     "E",       1L,
      "C",     "C",       7L,
      "C",     "D",       5L,
      "C",     "E",       2L,
      "D",     "D",       5L,
      "D",     "E",       1L,
      "E",     "E",       3L
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x=bill_2, y=bill_1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = overlap)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=overlap), colour = "white", check_overlap = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate the help, and sorry for the poorly-worded question. This is excellent!